# iOS UIPageControl without UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

It seems from Apple's tutorial that UIPageControl is dependant to UIScrollView. Can I just use UIPageControl on its own to navigate between Controllers? If it is possible, is there any example  [or possibly a code snippet] that I can read for this? What is the relationship between UIPageControl and UIScrollView?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fluchtpunkt is correct.  no relationship at all (other than they often go together).

here is a link to the UIPageControl

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and since you're asking... writing your own PageControl with your own custom graphics to fit your own needs and brand is extremely easy.  Let me know if are interested in some code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between those two. You can use an UIPageControl for whatever you want.